# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 631

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to apply bag-of-Words to a text dataset by running the following code:

But I get the following UnicodeDecodeError:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 631: 
>   invalid start byte

What does this mean and how can I fix this? What is position 631?

Regards!

Comment: E.g. `print(b'\xc5\xbe\xc3\xa1\x64\x6e\xc3\xbd\x20\x6b\xc3\xb3\x64'.decode('utf-8'))` returns `žádný kód`. It _roughly_ means _no code_ (in the question). The **631th** byte (zero-based) isn't a valid start byte in _utf-8_, e.g. like in   `print(b'\xfe\xbe\xc3\xa1\x64\x6e\xc3\xbd\'.decode('utf-8'))` returns `…  can't decode byte 0xfe in position 0: invalid start byte`.

Comment: Ok bthank you but how can I fix this? What do I need to do?

Comment: Show your code (follow rules of [mcve].

Comment: Fix formatting. Add [python] tag.

Comment: We cannot fix the problem without knowing the code that leads to the error...